# Editing Road Style/Color from ArcGIS Maps and Data Group

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers, editing, color

I have ArcMap 10.2 on a Windows 10 pc.

I uploaded this open source layer into my desktop map, but I can't edit the look of the streets or color from the table of contents. Is there a way to do this, maybe not from the Table of Contents?

Here's the link to the layer:http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fad13f5c12d946448dc8eb532664903f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adam, noted you cannot style the web service layers.  However you may download the related year shapefiles from here:

[National Transportation Atlas Database](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

That layer is an ArcGIS.com portal item (basically a web service), so you're unable to modify the symbology from how it is presented by ESRI.

Answer (score 0):

You are both correct, as I have tried many different ways to try to edit the symbology and failed. I've been using NTAD as my substitute and just had to select by attributes out the interstates and highways I wanted to keep.